# Compare two List<string> by value and index

Tags: c#, compare

I have two string collections and need to return any string value if the value doesn't exist in collection and index of value not equals. I implement with not exists condition, but I don't know add condition for index not equals.

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetInvalidHeaders(IEnumerable<string> list1, List<string> list2)
{            
     return list1.Where(header => list2 == null
                               || list2.All(x => x != header));
}
```

Values of collections must unique by value and index

Comment: I tried to decipher your question but couldn't do so. Can you rephrase it?

Comment: It's not really clear exactly what you mean. It would be very helpful if you could give sample input and output - particularly in cases where the lists aren't of the same length.

Comment: you may wanna use .Contains() list1.where( header => list2.contains(header))?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: I think you are going to check whether both list values are equal or not by array indexwise ????

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This accepts not only strings and uses deferred execution:

```
public IEnumerable<T> GetDifferences<T>(IList<T> seq1, IList<T> seq2)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < seq1.Count; i++)
    {
        T item1 = seq1[i];
        if (i >= seq2.Count)
            yield return item1;
        else
        {
            T item2 = seq2[i];
            if (!object.ReferenceEquals(item1, item2))
            {
                if (item1 == null || item2 == null)
                    yield return item1;
                else if (!item1.Equals(item2))
                    yield return item1;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
var diff = GetDifferences(list1, list2);
```

Comment: In the last part, why not just use `if (object.Equals(item1, item2))` and skip the extra cases with `null` and the reference equality test? If you want to avoid boxing in the value-type case, it can be written as `if (EqualityComparer<T>.Default.Equals(item1, item2))`.

Comment: Suggestion: Change signature from `IList<T> seq1, IList<T> seq2` to `IReadOnlyList<T> seq1, IReadOnlyList<T> seq2` since you only _read_ from `seq1` and `seq2`, and the reward you get is the covariance of `IReadOnlyList<out T>` which means that your method can be used in even more cases (with base and derived classes, for example).

Answer (score 4):

```
public IEnumerable<string> GetDifferences(List<string> list1, List<string> list2)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < list1.Count; i++)
    {
        if (list1[i] != list2[i]) yield return list1[i];
    }
}
```

Do you need something like that ?

Comment: Nice - after this then iterate `list2` for differences with `list1`.

Comment: If list1 have two items and list2 have one item I have System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException

Comment: Then you just have to replace the if statement by if (i >= list2.Count || list1[i] != list2[i])

Comment: Then, as StuartLC says, you duplicate the for, switching list1 and list2.